# How to check the difference between old and latest version dependencies?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies

I am using some old dependencies in my Android project. But now I am updating the dependencies to latest one. Before update how to check what are the changes is made in latest dependencies. Is there any tool or procedure to check the difference between two dependencies.

I am using `'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.3'`. Now the latest version is `'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'`. So before update I want to confirm that existing flow should not break. Many users are using my app. So please suggest me ideas to check the difference between two dependencies.

Comment: You can actually search release notes in google before you upgrade any dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check the changelog available [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/changelog/) or on Github.
But in your case, when you're upgrading to the next major version, all libraries usually provide some kind of migration tutorial. For okHttp v3 -> v4 you'll find it [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/upgrading_to_okhttp_4/).

Answer (score 0):

you can check the github page [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp) and view differences between branches as there is a one for pretty much every version.